# why do the error showing like "not resolved as a type or a field" in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new to `Android`.That's why I am asking this simple question. I am not able to understand. Here is my code. can you please explain?

Comment: show me your code where you got this error?

Comment: you should post ur code first

Answer (score 0):

The `R.java` file must not be getting generated. This usually happens when there is some error in your `res` folder, most probably in the `layout` files. Or you might have included **`import andorid.R`** in your project. If you have, then remove it and clean-build the project after making sure that there are no error in the xml files.